# In a containerized cluster, should mongodb servers be running on a worker or a core service?

Tags: mongodb, containers, cluster-computing, coreos

I'm trying to implement an architecture that's similar to the coreos's production architecture (shown below)

[image]

Should I run the database as a central service or one or more of the workers?

I figured the database needs some kind of replication, which makes me think that putting it in the worker cluster makes more sense, but I'm just not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be run as a worker.  The central services are the basic things that come with CoreOS (mainly etcd). The workers host your applications, the database being one of them.  You do have a persistence issue because your database will have state to remember between restarts.  So, there is a bigger issue of how do you make that persistence?  One was to do it is use a host file and give the database an affinity to that host and mount the host file.  Another thing you might consider is running more than one database (if your db technology supports that) and replicate that database so you have two (or more) copies in *different* workers. (non-affinity).  If your database creates transaction logs that can be applied to a backup, you can manage those transaction logs in a worker.

Another thing to consider is not using a container for your database.  The database is a weird animal, its care and feeding is not like the rest of the applications.  So it is reasonable (in my opinion) to have your database managed and maintained outside the scope of your cluster (but still reachable by the cluster).